# I2C Communication not working between 2 arduinos

Tags: c++, arduino, communication, i2c

I'm trying to have two Arduino's communicate with each other through I2C. I'm trying to send a string from the transmitter to the receiver, and have the receiver receive it and put it into a SD card. The if(Wire.available() > 0) doesn't execute either, and I'm not sure if it's a problem with the transmitter or receiver or hardware. For hardware I have A4 - > A4, A5 -> A5, and GND to GND. I'm not sure why the communication doesn't get received or transmitted. Here is the code that I am running -

Transmitter:

```
void setup(){
   Serial.begin(115200);
   Wire.begin();
}

void loop(){
    Wire.beginTransmission(9); 
    Wire.write("GPS: ");
    Wire.write(Latitude + Longitude).c_str());

    Wire.write("Altitude: ");
    Wire.write((Altitude).c_str());

    Wire.write(("Parachute: " + ReceivedParachuteStatus).c_str());
    
    digitalWrite(interruptPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(interruptPin, LOW);
    Wire.endTransmission();
}
```

Receiver:

```
void interruptServiceRoutine() {
  if (Wire.available() > 0) {
    if (SD.begin(CS_PIN)) {
      failCounter = 0;
      failCounterCOM = 0;
      LED_Trigger = true;

      incomingString = Wire.read(); 
      File SD_file = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_WRITE);

      SD_file.print(incomingString);
      Serial.println(incomingString);
      SD_file.close();
    } else {
        if (SD.begin(CS_PIN)) {
          failCounter++;
          
          File SD_file = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_WRITE);
          SD_file.println("SD Card Connection Fail: " + failCounter);
        }

      Serial.println("SD Card Connection Fail: " + failCounter);
      SD_file.close();
    }
   } else {
    if (SD.begin(CS_PIN)) {
      failCounterCOM++;
      
      File SD_file = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_WRITE);
      SD_file.println("Master MCU COM fail: " + failCounterCOM);
    }
    
    Serial.println("Master MCU COM fail: " + failCounterCOM);
    SD_file.close();
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin(9);

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), interruptServiceRoutine, RISING);

  if (!SD.begin(CS_PIN)) 
    Serial.println("Failed to connect to SD card");
}
```

Comment: Is the receiver on I2C address 9 and is it configured as slave?

Comment: yes, you can see that for yourself in the code.

Comment: I can't see in the code if that is the correct address.

Comment: In the setup function in the receiver I said Wire.begin(9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that incomingString = Wire.read(); should be in the receiveEvent(); function. You need one of those.And that is in the Wire.onReceive thing. Pretty much now my code is updated to -

````
void receiveEvent(int bytes){
  incomingString = Wire.read();
}
void interruptServiceRoutine() {
  if (Wire.available() > 0) {
    if (SD.begin(CS_PIN)) {
      failCounter = 0;
      failCounterCOM = 0;
      LED_Trigger = true;

      File SD_file = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_WRITE);

      SD_file.print(incomingString);
      Serial.println(incomingString);
      SD_file.close();
    } else {
        if (SD.begin(CS_PIN)) {
          failCounter++;
          
          File SD_file = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_WRITE);
          SD_file.println("SD Card Connection Fail: " + failCounter);
        }

      Serial.println("SD Card Connection Fail: " + failCounter);
      SD_file.close();
    }
   } else {
    if (SD.begin(CS_PIN)) {
      failCounterCOM++;
      
      File SD_file = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_WRITE);
      SD_file.println("Master MCU COM fail: " + failCounterCOM);
    }
    
    Serial.println("Master MCU COM fail: " + failCounterCOM);
    SD_file.close();
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Wire.begin(9);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);

  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), interruptServiceRoutine, RISING);

  if (!SD.begin(CS_PIN)) 
    Serial.println("Failed to connect to SD card");
}```
````